# Carbon Bike Frame Chip At Rear Wheel

Tags: frames, repair, carbon

I was wondering if this is fixable?

[image: Bike chip]

Answer (score 2):

You should be fine. That area appears to just be part of the dropout's axle locating recess. I don't see it taking much of the tensile load. It almost looks like it was intentional too; carbon fiber composite does not chip like glass does. You usually don't get flakes of the material simply falling off like that.

Comment: OP should consider cleaning it really well, drying, and then applying something to seal the area.  5 coats of enamel nail polish would work well, if spread out over a day.